# I am not able to connect to mqtt server from node.js

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I am completely new to mqtt and node.js i want to get data from mqtt server at regular intervals and populate in my html5 page

Here is the sample code that am try to connect but not sure it is right way or not

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

// connect to the message server
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org');

// publish 'Hello mqtt' to 'test'
client.publish('test', 'Hello mqtt');

// terminate the client
client.end()
```

Comment: Your sample code is javascript yet you've said your using c#. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really are working purely with node.js you haven't given the client time to actually connect before trying to publish a message.

The node.js [mqtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) module README has a full example (which it appears you've copied and removed most of the important bits from). I have removed the subscription part from the demo code, but this is the bare minimum needed to publish a message.

```
var mqtt    = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org');

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.publish('test', 'Hello mqtt');
  client.end();
});
```

Comment: Thankyou hardlib but my application is not connecting to mqtt://test.mosquitto.org i have to run mosquitto server in my local system?

Comment: You comment is not clear if you are just failing to connect to `test.mosquitto.org` or you do not want to connect to `test.mosquitto.org`. The given example works properly and connects just fine to `test.mosquitto.org` but as the name implies it should only be used for testing, if you want to do anything more you really should run your own broker.

Answer (score 0):

Following code upload data on hivemq MQTT Broker at regular interval.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
// connect to the message server
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://broker.hivemq.com');
client.on('connect', function () {
    setInterval(function () { client.publish('mytopic', 'Hello mqtt') }, 1000)
})
```

If you want to retrieve that data then use the following function

```
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    // message is Buffer
    console.log(message.toString())
    client.end()
})
```